# Using string length to set up array

Tags: java, arrays, string

I'm trying to assign a number to each letter in a sentence depending on what letter it is.

However, when trying to set up the array using the String length it breaks idk why.

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uFSLe.png)

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class cypher {

    static Scanner obj = new Scanner(System.in);

    static String initial_sent;
    static char char_single;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Instert sentence to be converted:");
        initial_sent = obj.next();
        initial_sent.toLowerCase();
        String[] char_array = new String[initial_sent.length()];

        for(int i = 0; i < initial_sent.length(); i++){

            char_single = initial_sent.charAt(i);

            switch(char_single){
                case 'a':
                    char_array[i] = "1";
                break;

                case 'b':
                    char_array[i] = "2";
                break;

                case 'c':
                    char_array[i] = "3";
                break;

                case 'd':
                    char_array[i] = "4";
                break;

                case 'e':
                    char_array[i] = "5";
                break;

                case 'f':
                    char_array[i] = "6";
                break;

                case 'g':
                    char_array[i] = "7";
                break;

                case 'h':
                    char_array[i] = "8";
                break;

                case 'i':
                    char_array[i] = "9";
                break;

                case 'j':
                    char_array[i] = "10";
                break;

                case 'k':
                    char_array[i] = "11";
                break;

                case 'l':
                    char_array[i] = "12";
                break;
                
                case 'm':
                    char_array[i] = "13";
                break;

                case 'n':
                    char_array[i] = "14";
                break;

                case 'o':
                    char_array[i] = "15";
                break;

                case 'p':
                    char_array[i] = "16";
                break;

                case 'q':
                    char_array[i] = "17";
                break;

                case 'r':
                    char_array[i] = "18";
                break;

                case 's':
                    char_array[i] = "19";
                break;

                case 't':
                    char_array[i] = "20";
                break;

                case 'u':
                    char_array[i] = "21";
                break;

                case 'v':
                    char_array[i] = "22";
                break;

                case 'w':
                    char_array[i] = "23";
                break;

                case 'x':
                    char_array[i] = "24";
                break;

                case 'y':
                    char_array[i] = "25";
                break;

                case 'z':
                    char_array[i] = "26";
                break;

                default:
                    char_array[i] = "0";
                break;

            }

        }

        System.out.println(char_array);

        obj.close();

    }

}
```

For example when sending the line "aabb", I want it to return "1122", but instead it send this gibberish "[Ljava.lang.String;@3b9a45b3".

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're printing an array and that is the default implementation of `toString` for an array - see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/409795/17856705) for printing array of strings.  A note on your logic: how does one differentiate `26` as being 'b' and 'f' vs 'z' when it is printed.  In other words "bf" produces "26" as well as "z".

Comment: *initial_sent.toLowerCase();* does nothing btw - `String` is immutable, so you need to assign the result. Also, in Java, underscores [belong only in the names of constants, or as digit-block separators](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/106-java-style-conventions)

Comment: A common question at Stack Overflow is about getting something like the "gibberish" when printing an array. For one, see  [How do I print my Java object without getting "SomeType@2f92e0f4"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29140402/how-do-i-print-my-java-object-without-getting-sometype2f92e0f4)

Comment: In addition to the issue of printing out an array, your code indicates you have some confusion about `char` and `String`.  You should be getting a compiler error at each line that looks like `char_array[i] = "1";` You should not have been able to run the code you've shown. You would not have gotten  `[Ljava.lang.String;@3b9a45b3` for output.

Comment: Yes, and further to that: *For example when sending the line "aabb", I want it to return "1122"* You don't. You want it to return `{ "1", "1", "2", "2" }` or you won't know if you got 11,2,2 say or indeed other combinations

Comment: This isn't the finished program as I will later convert the result to a string and every number will be separated by commas. I just wanted to break every problem step by step while writing the code. Also thanks for answers.

Comment: Unless the question is about a compiler error, we want code in questions to be code that compiles cleanly.

Comment: from the [tour], still not completed by you: "Don't ask about... * Questions you haven't tried to find an answer for" -- you should find plenty of similar problems searching for "[java] [arrays] gibberish"(tags, word used in your question): https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+%5Barrays%5D+gibberish+

Comment: *I will later convert the result to a string and every number will be separated by commas* although too advanced for your purposes (which is why I'm not giving it as an answer), you might be interested in the following, which produces just what you mentioned: `return input.toLowerCase().codePoints().filter(c ->c >= 'a' && c <= 'z').mapToObj(c ->Integer.toString(c - 'a' + 1)).collect(Collectors.joining(", "));` Of course, if you've got alphabetic mixed with other characters, then it will omit those other characters, which might not be what you want. Perhaps you want to ignore them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First store the output of `.toLowerCase()` to a String variable to process it further. To print the Array `char_array`, you should combine its members and store it in a string like I have done here. The members of `char_array` are combined in String `result`. Now you can print the `result`.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
    
    public class cypher {
    
      static Scanner obj = new Scanner(System.in);
    
      static String initial_sent;
      static char char_single;
    
      public static void main(String[] args) {
    
        System.out.println("Instert sentence to be converted:");
        initial_sent = obj.next();
        initial_sent = initial_sent.toLowerCase();
        String[] char_array = new String[initial_sent.length()];
    
        for (int i = 0; i < initial_sent.length(); i++) {
    
          char_single = initial_sent.charAt(i);
    
          switch (char_single) {
          case 'a':
            char_array[i] = "1";
            break;
    
          case 'b':
            char_array[i] = "2";
            break;
    
          case 'c':
            char_array[i] = "3";
            break;
    
          case 'd':
            char_array[i] = "4";
            break;
    
          case 'e':
            char_array[i] = "5";
            break;
    
          case 'f':
            char_array[i] = "6";
            break;
    
          case 'g':
            char_array[i] = "7";
            break;
    
          case 'h':
            char_array[i] = "8";
            break;
    
          case 'i':
            char_array[i] = "9";
            break;
    
          case 'j':
            char_array[i] = "10";
            break;
    
          case 'k':
            char_array[i] = "11";
            break;
    
          case 'l':
            char_array[i] = "12";
            break;
    
          case 'm':
            char_array[i] = "13";
            break;
    
          case 'n':
            char_array[i] = "14";
            break;
    
          case 'o':
            char_array[i] = "15";
            break;
    
          case 'p':
            char_array[i] = "16";
            break;
    
          case 'q':
            char_array[i] = "17";
            break;
    
          case 'r':
            char_array[i] = "18";
            break;
    
          case 's':
            char_array[i] = "19";
            break;
    
          case 't':
            char_array[i] = "20";
            break;
    
          case 'u':
            char_array[i] = "21";
            break;
    
          case 'v':
            char_array[i] = "22";
            break;
    
          case 'w':
            char_array[i] = "23";
            break;
    
          case 'x':
            char_array[i] = "24";
            break;
    
          case 'y':
            char_array[i] = "25";
            break;
    
          case 'z':
            char_array[i] = "26";
            break;
    
          default:
            char_array[i] = "0";
            break;
    
          }
    
        };
        String result = "";
        for (String key: char_array) {
          result = result + key;
        };
        System.out.println(result);
      }
    }
```

If you want a separate the numbers in the result, you can edit the for loop and add `", "` to separate the numbers like-

```
String result = "";
for (String key: char_array) {
  result = result + key+ ", ";
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Basic solution is your problem is this code. You did this complex way. Not necessary, not recommended.

```
package org.example;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Solution.run("aabb");
    }
}

class Solution {
    public static void run(String input)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for (var ch : input.toCharArray())
            if (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z')
                sb.append(ch - 'a' + 1);

        System.out.println(sb);
    }
}
```